# Alter table modify column on a huge table containing more than 25 million records

Tags: sybase, alter-table

I want to modify a column on a huge table containing more than 25 million records. I am using sybase 12.5.4. I have read through these posts

[What is the most efficient way to alter a column definition in a table with millions of rows](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-alter-a-column-definition-in-a-table-with-mill)

and

[ALTER TABLE on a large table with an indexed column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3760/alter-table-on-a-large-table-with-an-indexed-column)

My current strategy is

- Drop all non clustered index
- Drop clustered index
- Alter table modifcy column varchar (32) -- column is char(20) presently
- Recreate clustered index
- recreate non clustered index

Does it make sense. Is there a faster method do it ?

Edit :

- Table Data Size : 16.7 GB
- Total rows : 25835155
- avg row size : .64 KB
- 8  Non Clustered Index
- Yes,column I am changing is the second column in a 2 column NC index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only need to drop and recreate the affected NC index.

Saying that, on a test server, you can see the differences in doing this compared to your strategy of dropping all indexes above.

I reckon dropping/creating the single index would be quicker overall because the data will be shifted around twice otherwise: once char to varchar, another to build the clustered index. Then you have the NC creation overhead.